# Is there a web browser I can use safely on Mac OS 10.5.8?

Tags: google-chrome, leopard, firefox, web-browser

Sometime in 2012, Adobe Flash asked me to update it. I tried, but it didn't work because my browsers (firefox and chrome) didn't support the newest flash. I tried to update my browsers, but neither firefox nor chrome supports mac os 10.5.8 anymore. Safari keeps telling me to update flash too. I know that using an older version of flash can be a security hazard, so I really want to update.

My question: Are there any browsers (perhaps a firefox variant) I can use more safely now than the browsers that shipped with 10.5.8?

Comment: PowerPC or Intel?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should try opera [Opera 12 download](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/) it fast and works well.

Caveat:  Opera only works on Macs with Intel-based processors.  If you have a PowerPC chip (G5), good luck.  Opera 12 won't work.

Answer (score 6):

*For the impatient:*

You have two possibilities:

- PowerPC-based Mac: [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/) and no Flash.
- Intel-based Mac: [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/requirements) (thanks to [Cybermatatu](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/43310/cybermatatu) for this one!) with  [older Flash 10.3](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/completion/?installer=Flash_Player_10.3_for_Mac_OS_X_10.4_-_10.5_%28Intel%29) (beware, Flash 10.3 is an archived version and is [no longer supported nor updated with security fixes by Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)).

*Long version:*

- If you use an Intel processor you can use [Opera](http://www.opera.com/browser/download/requirements):

  > Opera 12
  >
  > OS X Leopard (10.5), or greater: 32-bit and 64-bit Intel
  >   systems supported

  Opera supports Flash Player plug-in.
- If you use a PowerPC processor you may want to try [TenFourFox](http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/). TenFourFox seems to be actively developed (version 17.0.3 was released Feb 16 2013). TenFourFox supports add-ons, but not plugins, that is, **you can't use Flash at all**.

Please notice that Flash Player 11 [only supports 10.6 and newer](http://www.adobe.com/products/flashplayer/tech-specs.html). You can still download [version 10.3](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) for 10.5 Intel (beware, Flash 10.3 is an archived version and is [no longer supported nor updated with security fixes by Adobe](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html)).

As for other browsers:

- **Firefox** [no longer supports PowerPC](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-no-longer-works-mac-os-10-4-or-powerpc) processors (PowerBook, PowerMac):

  > Firefox 3.6.28 is the last version of Firefox that works with Mac OS X
  >   10.4 (Tiger) or with Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) on a computer with a PowerPC processor.

  [Firefox 16](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/16.0/system-requirements/) is the latest version that supports Leopard on Intel-based Macs as Firefox 17 requires 10.6 or newer.
- Apple no longer releases **Safari** updates for Mac OS X 10.5 (as stated [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Safari_%28web_browser%29#System_requirements)).
- **Chrome** [doesn't support Leopard](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2599452), either:

  > Google Chrome on Mac OS X 10.5 (Leopard) will stop receiving any
  >   updates following Chrome 21.

Comment: [Adobe Technical Support doesn't provide support for installation or use](http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html) of archived versions of Flash Player. As I read Adobe's page: whilst Flash Player 10.3.183.90 (the *software*) supports Mac OS X 10.5, Adobe (the *developer*) does not. Without that support from Adobe, I should not treat use of outdated Flash Player as safe.

Comment: I seem to remember that back in February (when I first answered the question) the article linked (http://helpx.adobe.com/flash-player/kb/find-version-flash-player.html) listed a Flash Player for Mac OS X 10.5.x. So I inferred that Adobe supported that Flash version too. However, since it wasn't stated explicitely, I chose the wording "which seems to be supported by Adobe". That's clearly no longer the case (extended support for Flash Player 10.3 expired on July 9th, as explained in the link your provided), thanks for pointing it out, I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry! I had overlooked the extended support aspect; didn't realise that the 10.3.x series was updated as recently as 2013-07-09!

Comment: VNC->Browser through that newer Mac you keep upstairs, running 10.12.6, should work. You do not *have* to run the browser on the machine you are sitting at. Yes, it's claptrap and kludgery, but there *are* reasons to keep these older machines around. 10.5.8.11 *e.g.* is the last OS that you can still run System 9 under.

Answer (score 5):

I have had some success in a Flash-less world by using Safari, and enabling the **Develop** menu. Then when I get to a page that requires Flash, I can set the User Agent to report as an iPad and I will get videos streamed in a QuickTime player rather than Flash-based.

Answer (score 2):

I really like the following 2 browsers.  They work even on 10.4.11

- [OmniWeb](http://www.omnigroup.com/products/omniweb/)
- [Camino](http://www.caminobrowser.org)

Comment: Can you add some details about thinks you especially like and which make these browsers stand out?

Comment: Camino is no longer being developed, unfortunately. I, too, recommend OmniWeb.

Answer (score 0):

SeaMonkey. Still works with my old Salad bowl PPC iMac (1 GHz, 768 MB RAM), and supports flash.

Answer (score 0):

The [build requirements for firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Developer_Guide/Build_Instructions/Mac_OS_X_Prerequisites) indicate that it should build on your setup. Might be worth a try.

Anyway going without flash is definetly the future.

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome v15 still works on Intel Leopard 10.5.8,
IF, you can find a copy..
PS.. I'm using it now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using iCab 5.1.1, it's working where Firefox won't.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  We're trying to find the best answers and those answers will provide info as to why they're the best.  Answers should be self-contained so explain why you think the answer you provided will solve the problem or is better than others out there.  Providing links as supporting information can also help the OP, and others, find additional info for themselves.  See [answer] on how to provide a quality answer. - From Review

Answer (score 0):

Tenfourfox fpr4 is the latest Tenfourfox version for your PowerPC MAC's running Mac OS 10.5.8.

It is a Feature Parity Release 4 is a feature, performance, bugfix and security update incorporating security and stability patches from Firefox 52 ESR and new features from recent versions of Firefox

at http://www.floodgap.com/software/tenfourfox/